# How to fix looping with Response.Redirect eventually causing a page timeout?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a page that I am building a large number of files in a folder. Once completed, I zip up the folder and deliver to the client a download link. I save the list of files in a database, process 1 file, flag that entry in the database and then Response.Redirect back to my same page. It will then read the next database entry and do the same until all entries are completed.

My page is timing out and I want to either add some code that will tell it not to time out or perhaps redirect using javascript. I would rather not have to render my page to the client every time.

I have tried setting the timeout in the page init class.
Server.ScriptTimeout = 60 * 60 * 60

This did not help.

Comment: Why are you re-directing and not doing this asynchronous? you can just have a javascript function loop over the folders right? and then have that do an ajax call. and update the result on the page?

Comment: I am using telerik server code call of ExportToExcel()

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment above, I would go with an asynchronous approach.
Redirecting seems like a terrible idea and it blocks your UI.

Javascript pseudo code ish:

```
$(folders).forEach(function(folder) {
    var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function(data) {
        $("#idofyourdownloadlink").text("Processing");
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#idofyourdownloadlink").append("<a href="+data+">Download</a>");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $("#idofyourdownloadlink").text("Failed to process");
    })
});
```

you can re-write the code to run in a while loop and do time-outs on your requests if your server gets overloaded too.

in C# do your processing and return the link. don't redirect with new data.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a promise for each folder , then when all promises are completed you can start listing links on you page , it goes something like this :

```
var foldersArray = ['folder1', 'folder2'];
var promisesList = [];

function addFolderToDatabase(file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.post("index.php",{"file":file})
            .done(function(response) {
                resolve(response);
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            })
    });
}


$(foldersArray).each(function(){
    var returnedPromise = addFolderToDatabase(this);
    promisesList.push(returnedPromise);
});


Promise.all(promisesList).then(function(){
   // DO WHAT YOU WANNA DO
   // THIS CALL BACK FUNCTION MEANS THAT ALL FOLDERS ARE COMPLETED
});
```

CHEERS,